# Duplicates by few rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, duplicates

I have a table:

```
model1 model2 speed  ram
-----  ------ ------ ----
1121   1233   750    128
1232   1233   500    64
1232   1260   500    32
1233   1121   750    128
1233   1232   500    64
1260   1232   500    32
```

And I need to remove duplicate pairs of model1 and model2.

Here these rows are 4-6. Looking at the first row:

```
model1 1121     model2 1233
```

the duplicate is

`model1  1233    model2   1121` 
etc.

Meant if model1+model2 = model2+model1 - that is a duplicate.

I've tried using such quesry:

```
where cast(model1 as char(4))+cast(model2 as char(4))<>cast(model1 as char(4))+cast(model2 as char(4))
```

. How can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to select unique records or delete the duplicates?

Comment: I want to delete the duplicate pairs of model1 and model2. So if model1+model2 = model2+model1 - that record should be deleted

Comment: maybe you could deal with the concatenation of the sorted ids with some separator in the middle as a string. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: What DB engine do you use? The syntax differ for some of them.

Comment: I use MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, use at your own risk, but it could serve as starting point

to see unique only:

```
select model1,model2 from T
EXCEPT
select model2,model1 from T where model2 > model1;
```

Comment: I've trying using intersect, it doesn't work. And I don't need to delete duplicates I neeed just to return unique by query. Thank u

Comment: That's odd. Would you mind posting the error you're getting when you use intersect ? To only see the unique, use EXCEPT instead of INTERSECT

Comment: if your table only contains duplicates, that means it's working :) I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter out duplicates from your results, seems like it should be simply:

```
where cast(model1 as char(4))+cast(model2 as char(4))<>cast(model1 as char(4))+cast(model2 as char(4))
AND cast(model1 as char(4))+cast(model2 as char(4))<>cast(model2 as char(4))+cast(model1 as char(4))
```

If you want to SELECT the duplicates for deletion, then turn it around like this:

```
where cast(model1 as char(4))+cast(model2 as char(4))=cast(model1 as char(4))+cast(model2 as char(4))
OR cast(model1 as char(4))+cast(model2 as char(4))=cast(model2 as char(4))+cast(model1 as char(4))
```

Comment: I guess I need to get the first of your sentence, but it returns the empty result((

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  What is the full query you are executing that returns an empty result?

Comment: I'm using the first of ur query.

Answer (score 1):

To select duplicates as you've defined them:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 a
WHERE EXISTS (  SELECT *
                FROM Table1 b 
                WHERE  a.model1 = b.model2
                 AND   a.model2 = b.model1
             )
AND model2 < model1
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ab89/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

First, you should improve your INSERTS, if you sort your values before inserting there should be no further duplicates.

To remove all rows where another, sorted combination exists use this:

```
DELETE FROM table
FROM table t1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT NULL
  FROM table t2 
  WHERE t2.model1 = t1.model2
  AND t2.model2 = t1.model1)
WHERE t1.model2 > t1.model1
```

This should work in mssql 2005 and later, but I can't check the syntax right now. Updating the remaining data to sorted columns should be simple from here : )

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I'm trying to to test ur answer.